# Extract Fingerprint from Image

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing

I have been working on Touch less Bio-metrics. I want to extract Fingerprints from image captured by normal mobile camera. I have achieved a good image, but it is not good enough to be verified by government.

The lines need to be more thick and connected.

### What I have tried so far?

Below are the steps which I took to extract a fingerprint from image. It is good, but lines are disconnected and joined with other.

1. Changed contrast and brightness to 0.8 and 25 respectively
2. Converted from RGB to Gray
3. Applied histogram equalization
4. Normalized image
5. Applied adaptive (gaussian c) threshold for block size of 15 and constant 2
6. Smooth image to get rid of edges
7. Changed contrast and brightness again to 1.7 and -40 respectively
8. Applied Gaussian Blur
9. Add weight (alpha = 0.5, beta = -0.5 and gamma = 0)
10. Applied binary threshold (threshold = 10)

Original Image would be like this (I missed the original image of processed image)

[image]

And the result is the image attached (processed image).

[image]

I need lines to be more connected and separated from other lines so that **Ridge Ending** and **Ridge Bifurcation** can easily be identified.

I also came through [this link](https://l.messenger.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fanswers.opencv.org%2Fquestion%2F6364%2Ffingerprint-matching-in-mobile-devices-android-platform%2F&h=ATOXn91e0Jel8sXcq8AEsdIkaWm2GNm_cCf7JGlTbgJlK0yFSKOGBkJ80MyRbuK4tuj2VCQRjHWwxqDveXQO6TtEvLNMpWuDEr7842SwIdWDUD85-Mq0OzZrpP_HB0Fp-49l8tbajZP2jg), but due to very limited background in Image Processing, I am unable to understand this. Any guidance regarding this link can also help me a lot.

I am using `opencv` in `Android`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your original image?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Your original image is not corresponding to your processed image. And the original image's contrast is not good. The link you post suggests to do `gabor filter`, maybe it's a choice. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqkwW.jpg

Comment: Yes, it isn't. I lost original image of this processed image. And I have idea that `Gabor Filter` is a choice, but I am facing difficulty in using it. I don't know how to use it according to my need. Your guide is really helpful.

Comment: Maybe you can ask in OpenCV forum.

Comment: I suggest you can look in the areas of image enhancement and image denoising.

Comment: @Silencer would you please tell me what are the techniques you have used for the processing in image you have shared in your comment.  [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqkwW.jpg)

Comment: @WaqasAhmedAnsari did you got sollution to this?

Comment: I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score -1):

I saw a video on Youtube related to RayTracing on video games rendering, and there I could see that the Q2VKPT engine creator uses a "Temporal Filter" using multiple frames to get a clear image (ASVGF).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbsudki8Sro
from 26:20 to 28:40

Maybe, if you have three different images for the fingerprints and then you use a similar approach, you could get a picture with less noise that works better.